# Filtering matched content

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to Filter all content after match with the content and bring the first value after the "."

I have an output something like this:

Output:

```
product: 13.6.0.35_0
```

More specifically, I need only the first two digits and the first digit after the dot, remembering that we should not cling to the values in the issue, but rather on the method of filtering the content.

Expected:

```
13.6
```

I tried something like:

```
echo "product: 13.6.0.35_0" | grep -ow '\w*13\w*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `grep` with the current logic, you can use

```sh
echo "product: 13.6.0.35_0" | grep -ow '13\.[0-9]*' | head -1
```

where `13\.[0-9]*` matches `13`, `.` and zero or more digits (as whole word due to `w` option) and `head -1` gets the first match.

You may also use `sed` or `awk`:

```sh
sed -En 's/.* ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/p' <<< "product: 13.6.0.35_0"
awk -F'[[:space:].]' '{print $2"."$3}' <<< "product: 13.6.0.35_0"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/hfRBd9).

The `sed` command matches any text up to space, then matches the space and captures the two subsequent dot-separated numbers into Group 1 (`\1`) and then the rest of the line is matched and replaced with Group 1 value that is printed (as the default line output is suppressed with `-n`).

In the `awk` command, the field separator is set to whitespace and `.` with `-F'[[:space:].]'` and the `{print $2"."$3}` part prints the second and third field values joined with a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

A pure shell solution using the builtin `read` , Parameter Expansion and curly braces for command groupings.

```
echo "product: 13.6.0.35_0" | { read -r _ value; echo "${value%.*.*}" ; }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I reached the expected output, it's simple but it works:

```
var=$(echo "product: 13.6.0.35_0" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' | sed -n 1,2p)
echo ${var} | sed 's/ /./g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cut`:

```
 echo 'product: 13.6.0.35_0' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '.' -f1-2
 13.6
```